# Coda SVN with self signed SSL

Tags: svn, ssl, coda

Seems to be a few [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) users here.  Does anyone use SVN with a self-signed cert in Coda?  It throws an error that the cert isn't valid, and doesn't give the option to ignore it.  Is there any way to get it to work?  I've emailed Panic support, and haven't heard back yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://phildawson.tumblr.com/post/49709765/solved-coda-server-certificate-verification-failed

Answer (score 1):

In case Phil ever changes [that URL](http://phildawson.tumblr.com/post/49709765/solved-coda-server-certificate-verification-failed):

1. If you haven’t already, install svn for mac
2. In a Terminal type svn list and your repos

   ```
   svn list https://www.example.com/svn/
   ```

Type p to confirm and the certification will be cached.

If you get svn command not found then open up the profile file and add /usr/local/bin to the PATH and try again

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```